# issue with has_many, through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

For some reason, my has_many through association isn't working. Here are my models:

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :evints
  has_many :events, through: :evints
  has_many :images, through: :events

end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :evints
  has_many :images
  has_many :interests, through: :evints

end

class Evint < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :events
  belongs_to :interests

end
```

The Evints table has three columns: interest_id, event_id, and id.

When I call @interest.events, I get the error message

```
uninitialized constant Interest::Events
```

Obviously, there's something going wrong with the association if @interest.events is being read as a constant!

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is assigned to @interest?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Evint class, it should be:

```
class Evint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :interest
end
```

On a different note, I think Evint isn't really a very good name. It'd suggest that you go with EventInterest, and name the table event_interests.

Comment: Thanks for you input! I started with EventInterest, but the underscore kept getting in my way, so Evints was my solution. And I do have Evint belonging to both event and interest . . .

Comment: It's `belongs_to :event` and `belongs_to :interest` (singular). You're using plural in the question.